# Error saving resized image

Tags: c#, .net, image, winforms, resize-image

I have the following code

```
int oswidth = 0;
int osheight = 0;

        if (comboBox3.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            oswidth = Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text.ToString());
            osheight = Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text.ToString());
        }
        else if (comboBox3.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            oswidth = 38 * Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text.ToString());
            osheight = 38 * Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text.ToString());


        }

        Bitmap oldimg = new Bitmap(pictureBox3.Image);
        Bitmap objBitmap = new Bitmap(oldimg, new Size(oswidth, osheight));
        objBitmap.Save(pictureBox3.ImageLocation.ToString(), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

The problem is when the selected index is 0 it works fine
but when the selected index is 1 i get a error "Parameter is not valid."
i tried different images but same error. is it the multiply by 32 thing

Comment: What is the (string) value of `pictureBox3.ImageLocation`?

Comment: "C:\Users\Kalpesh\Desktop\New folder\New folder\P.png"

Comment: I hit a limit __creating__ a `Bitmap` at around 340M pixels an and get a 'parameter error'   When trying to __save__ the `Bitmap`as `png` I hit the limit at 66M pixels and get a 'general GDI+ error'.

Answer (score 2):

The `Parameter is not valid` error message when trying to create a Bitmap usually means that you are trying to allocate too much memory to it. The bitmap requires `bit-depth*width*height/8` bytes of **contiguous** memory, and there just isn't enough available to satisfy that.

In this case, it looks like it's because you're multiplying its dimensions by 38 (and therefore multiplying the size in memory by 38^2).

Comment: oswidth 38912 int &
osheight 29184 int

Is that too much??

Comment: You would need 4.5GB of memory to store that image. That's definitely too much.

Why do you need to multiply the dimensions by 38?

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize the following method:

```
private static void ResizeImage(string file, double vscale, double hscale, string output)
{
     using(var source = Image.FromFile(file))
     {
          var width = (int)(source.Width * vscale);
          var height = (int)(source.Height * hscale);
          using(var image = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
               using(var graphic = Graphics.FromImage(image))
               {
                    graphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                    graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    graphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                    graphic.DrawImage(source, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
                    image.Save(output);
               }
     }
}
```

You can tailor this however you'd like, but it should meet your needs.

**Important:** The reason `vscale` and `hscale` are separate is to not follow scaling.  You can easily combine them so you can scale accordingly.  The other thing to remember, is your using a value of `32`.  Try using a value of `.32` which will treat it more like a percent, which will scale.  Also it won't increase the memory drastically causing your error.